# TFS Database Backup Failed : There is an error in XML document

Tags: xml, tfs, backup

This is very much a duplicate of a question asked in

[TFS Database Backup Failed : There is an error in XML document - but which Doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303842/tfs-database-backup-failed-there-is-an-error-in-xml-document-but-which-doc)

and this is the quick summary.

**Problem:**

```
[8/25/2017 8:40:02 AM] [Info] Requested Backup Job: Transactional
[8/25/2017 8:40:02 AM] [Info] -------------------------------------------------------------------
[8/25/2017 8:40:02 AM] [Info] Jobs Requested: Transactional. Completed: None. To Run: Transactional.
[8/25/2017 8:40:02 AM] [Info] RunTransactionalBackupJob
[8/25/2017 8:40:02 AM] [Error] 
Exception Message: There is an error in XML document (23569, 23). (type InvalidOperationException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.BackupSets.Load(String folder)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Jobs.DatabaseBackupJob.RunTransactionalBackupJob(IVssRequestContext requestContext, BackupSettings settings, ITFLogger logger)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Jobs.DatabaseBackupJob.RunBackupJob(IVssRequestContext requestContext, BackupJobType requestedJobType, String& resultMessage)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: Unexpected end of file while parsing Name has occurred. Line 23569, position 23. (type XmlException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Int32 pos, String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseQName(Boolean isQName, Int32 startOffset, Int32& colonPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderBackupSets.Read5_TfsBackupSet(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderBackupSets.Read6_BackupSets(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderBackupSets.Read7_BackupSets()

[8/25/2017 8:40:02 AM] [Info] Backup Job Finished. Completed: Transactional. Result = Failed
```

**Explanation:**
TFS back failes due to being enabled to successfully parse the XML in the directory where the back ups are saved (BackupSets.xml)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFS Database Backup Failed : There is an error in XML document - but which Doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303842/tfs-database-backup-failed-there-is-an-error-in-xml-document-but-which-doc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:**

1. go to the directory where your back ups are stored
2. find "BackupSets.xml"
3. rename it to "BackupSets_BACKUP.xml" (or anything else of your liking)
4. rerun the full backup procedure in TFS Administration Console

As the result the BackupSets.xml will be recreated, and the problem should go away