# There is error in XML document(0,0) while recreating TFS backup plan

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I am getting an error while trying to recreate TFS Backup plan using backup tools "There is error in XML document(0,0)". I have already renamed the backupsets.xml file and tried, but still i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

After renamed the backupsets.xml, you also need to **perform a full data backup**.

> **FIX (user workaround):**
>
> 1. Rename the file **BackupSets.xml** in the **backup** destination folder
> 2. Re-run Full Backup
>
>    - *In TFS Admin Console select Scheduled Backups, then click Take Full Backup Now. Or use command line, PowerShell script, API call as
>        desired.*
>
> **CAUSE:** backupsets.xml in backup destination does **not contain valid XML**.

More details please take a look at below two similar issues:

- [TFS Database Backup Failed : There is an error in XML document - but which Doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303842/tfs-database-backup-failed-there-is-an-error-in-xml-document-but-which-doc)
- [TFS TF400983: There is an error in XML document](https://brosteins.com/2015/08/13/tfs-tf400983-there-is-an-error-in-xml-document/)

Comment: I have already renamed the backupsets.xml file, but still getting the same error. If you have any powershell script, please share it

Comment: @Sai You need to perform a full data backup, suggest you first go through the two blogs  post above. No need to use powershell script to rename the file, simply use file system's rename option. Besides, if rename not work, you could also  try to delete the Backupsets.xml file altogether
Reconfigured Backups using the wizard - Now that it didn't find the xml file at all it created a new one. More details please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25323991/5391065

Comment: I am getting this error when i tried to take the full backup (after renaming the backupsets.xml file)

Comment: @Sai Tried on my side with TFS2018, the backup plan and manually back up works properly. Suggest you to try this solution: Back up the renamed `XX.xml` file first, then directly delete the BackupSets.xml in the backup destination folder, then take the full backup, it should create a new  BackupSets.xml  file.